Using ADC DMA and TIMER in STM32H723ZG
I'm doing my first project on STM32. My board is STM32H723ZG. I am trying to sample analog signal using ADC. I set its sampling rate with TIMER6 and transfer data directly to DMA. I am actually following instructions in this video, doing the 3rd part.

ADC1 IN5 Single-ended Configuration 1st

ADC1 IN5 Single-ended Configuration 2nd

DMA configuration

TIMER6 configuration

Clock Configuration
I have just added a few lines of code into the code that the cubeIDE generated for me. I added them in their corresponding segments of the code.
Lines are:
#define buffer_size 128

uint32_t adc_buffer[buffer_size];
uint32_t adc_value;

adc_value = 0; 

HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, adc_buffer, buffer_size);

HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim6);

void HAL_ADC_ConvHalfCpltCallBack(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    adc_value = adc_buffer'['1];
}
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallBack(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{

}

I am using debug to monitor the value of variable adc_value and it never changes after initialization. First, I thought there was a problem with DMA configuration because I could not find an option 'DMA continuous request' as it's shown in the video. Then I found this link which lead me to this link where someone with username 'Kevin' had a similar problem as me. The solution for his problem was Option: 'Conversion Data Management Mode' — 'DMA circular Mode'. I tried that but no effect on my code. Now I think the problem should be with timer.
What do you think?

The code you've included seems ot have a bug in the way you're indexing the adc_buffer array in HAL_ADC_ConvHalfCpltCallBack(). Do you really have '1' there, meaning you're indexing the array with the ASCII character '1' (hex 0x31, decimal 49) instead of just the integer value 1?

I just could not figure out how to write rectangular brackets around number 1 when posting the question here and that's what I did.

Put a breakpoint inside the interrupt callback function (HAL_ADC_ConvHalfCpltCallback). Do you actually get there? If yes, do you get there repeatedly? If no, check the error code in the hadc1 and hdma structures and post them in your question. One problem I had with DMA on the H743 controller is that the linker script supplied by ST was "bad". It initialized all the variables into the DTCM memory, which is unfortunate sinve the DMA has no access to this special memory..

Another issue could be the clock config for ADC1, which you do not show in the screenshots. The clock could be simply set too slow for the targeted conversion rate. Keep in mind that the ADC needs 32.5 clock cycles for sampling with your Cube-MX settings + some additional ones (~20) for the SAR conversion. Hence, the ADC1 clock should be greater than ~53MHz

@Mau5 ADC clock is at 96MHz. Unfortunately my board's ST-Link is no longer functioning so I will have to postpone debugging. I think it was never entering HAL_ADC_ConvHalfCpltCallback.
